# Scapy sniffing on Windows

Tags: python, scapy

I run this code as administrator:

```
from scapy.all import *
def poison(packet):
    packet[TCP].flags='R'
    sendp(packet)
sniff(prn=poison,filter='tcp',iface='any')
```

And I have error:AttributeError None Type object has no attribute encode
What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed code sample? For some reason you are accessing an attribute on a value that is None, but without code it isn't exactly clear what could be going wrong.

Comment: It try to call "encode" method from device object.

Comment: Please,self.iface = create_string_buffer(device.encode('ascii'))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: @SpicyClutches what happens if you just leave out the "iface='any'" portion of the sniff command?  Scapy will sniff on all interfaces if you leave out that argument.

Comment: @ Noob123 There will be same error

Comment: @SpicyClutches looks like it may be an open issue.  Check these two links.  [link 1](https://github.com/phaethon/scapy/issues/47)  [link 2](https://github.com/phaethon/scapy/issues/86)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think setting `iface` to `"any"` is valid under Windows.

You can check by removing the `iface` parameter from your code (or by using a valid interface name).